# Store Item Level Blobs (Images) in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to store multiple images link to 1000s of items in SQL Server. For each record there can be multiple Images to be stored.

I will be using a single account for storing all documents. Though, within accounts Blob Storage allows segregation only by Containers.

Should I create 1000s of containers for each item to separate images? Or '/' notation is recommended in this scenario (link below with details on using forward slash to achieve hierarchy)? If images are stored with '/' notation, can the name of the image be preserved while rendering or when users are accessing it, without '/' in the name?

[Creating an Azure Blob Hierarchy](https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks79/)

Here is an example scenario -

`ItemID    Images`
`1         A1.jpg; A2.jpg; A32018.jpg`
`2         B1.jpg; B2.jpg; A32018.jpg`
`3         C1.jpg; C2.jpg; A32018.jpg`

As specified here, multiple items can have images with same names, but should be stored separately.

Comment: Will the image names be different?

Comment: I think it s depend if you need to search files ? blob storage allow you to list files inside a container and using a prefix, you need to keep this in mind

Answer (score -1):

The Azure blob storage have account/contianer/blob(s) 
There is one account, one container (could be called folder) but can have multiple blob (folders or files). This means that whatever is after container and whatever is the depth all are called as blob.

I don't understand still know that how you want to store the images but may be this will help.

In case I have two images image1.png and image2.png, it can be stored in below ways

Suppose account : imagedatastore

container : imagescontainer

You can keep both the images on imagescontainer such as

imagescontainer/image1.png

imagescontainer/image2.png

or can create separate containers for both images.

This is totally dependant on your segregation logic.

Comment: You can't create folders in containers, but you can create `virtual` folder structures via the name of your blob.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the same.